# Two identical code snippets given on the same directory level, one gets pylint import error the other does not

Tags: importerror, pylint

I have two tests, which both import the module to be tested. The code is exactly the same. One test gets an pylint import-error and the other does not.
Directory looks like this:

````
      /root
        /modules
          init.py
          module_to_test.py
        /tests
          /testcase one
            test_one.py
          /testcase_two
            test_two.py
    ```
    In the test code i used 
    ```
    BASEDIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    ROOTDIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.join(BASEDIR, os.pardir), os.pardir))
    sys.path.insert(0, ROOTDIR)
    from modules import module_to_test.py
````

The two test code snippets are identical, yet i get an pylint import Error in one but not in the other.

i tried passing the path via the settings.json to pylint directly, i tried the init-hook method, but nothing seems to work. What am i not seeing?

Content of the test file:

pylint error message:

```
"{
    "resource": "/c:/SourceTree/DIN743/p_test_DIN743/p_integration_kerbueberlagerung_1_test/p_integration_kerbueberlagerung_1_test.py",
    "owner": "python",
    "code": "import-error",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Unable to import 'p_DIN743'",
    "source": "pylint",
    "startLineNumber": 10,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 10,
    "endColumn": 1
}"
```

´´´

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os, sys
BASEDIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
ROOTDIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASEDIR, "../.."))
TOOLDIR = os.path.join(os.path.join(ROOTDIR, os.pardir), "tools")
sys.path.insert(0, ROOTDIR)
sys.path.insert(0, TOOLDIR)
import unittest
from p_DIN743 import m_DIN743
from tools import m_jsonhelper

class TestDIN743(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        # change cwd
        os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
        print("cwd changed to: {}".format(os.getcwd()))
        # check if inputs.json & soll_outputs.json exist 
        
        if not os.path.isfile("inputs.json"):
            print("inputs.json does not exist but is required!")

        if not os.path.isfile("soll_outputs.json"):
            print("soll_outputs.json does not exist but is required!")

        # create test object
        cls.__test_object = m_DIN743.DIN743()
        cls.__test_object.Run()
        cls.outputs = m_jsonhelper.loadjson("outputs.json")
        cls.soll_outputs = m_jsonhelper.loadjson("soll_outputs.json")

    def test_dicts(self):
        self.maxDiff = None
        self.assertDictEqual(TestDIN743.soll_outputs, TestDIN743.outputs)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

´´´

Comment: Your problem is hard to reproduce without the exact content of the file, and the exact pylint's output, could you edit your question to provide that ?

Comment: Done! I hope hte provided code helps